# GCP: Cloud Run preview build fails because of a missing tag "latest"

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

If have an issue where cloud build is failing on creating a preview build for use in github pull requests.

I have

- a github organization with the cloud build app installed.
- a cloud build set-up with triggers to deploy to cloud run
- functional build on master deploy (doesn't really matter here).

The following is my `cloudbuild-preview.yaml` file. The failing step is the last one: **"link revision on pull request"**

```
steps:
  - id: "build image"
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args:
      [
        "build",
        "-t",
        "$_GCR_HOSTNAME/${PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}:${_PR_NUMBER}-${SHORT_SHA}",
        ".",
      ]

  - id: "push image"
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args:
      [
        "push",
        "$_GCR_HOSTNAME/${PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}:${_PR_NUMBER}-${SHORT_SHA}",
      ]

  - id: "deploy revision with tag"
    name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk"
    entrypoint: "gcloud"
    args:
      [
        "beta",
        "run",
        "deploy",
        "${_SERVICE_NAME}",
        "--platform",
        "managed",
        "--region",
        "${_REGION}",
        "--image",
        "$_GCR_HOSTNAME/${PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}:${_PR_NUMBER}-${SHORT_SHA}",
        "--tag",
        "pr-${_PR_NUMBER}",
        "--no-traffic",
      ]

  - id: "link revision on pull request"
    name: "$_GCR_HOSTNAME/${PROJECT_ID}/deployment-previews" # our custom builder
    args:
      [
        "set",
        "--project-id",
        "${PROJECT_ID}",
        "--region",
        "${_REGION}",
        "--service",
        "${_SERVICE_NAME}",
        "--pull-request",
        "${_PR_NUMBER}",
        "--repo-name",
        "${_GITHUB_REPO}",
        "--commit-sha",
        "${SHORT_SHA}",
      ]
timeout: 1400s
options:
  machineType: N1_HIGHCPU_8
substitutions:
  _GCR_HOSTNAME: eu.gcr.io
  _SERVICE_NAME: redacted-service
  _REGION: europe-west4
  _GITHUB_REPO: $(pull_request.pull_request.head.repo.full_name)
```

The execution fails with

```
Step #3 - "link revision on pull request": Error response from daemon: manifest for eu.gcr.io/redacted-org/deployment-previews:latest not found: manifest unknown: Failed to fetch "latest" from request "/v2/redacted-org/deployment-previews/manifests/latest".
Step #3 - "link revision on pull request": Using default tag: latest
Step #3 - "link revision on pull request": Pulling image: eu.gcr.io/redacted-org/deployment-previews
Starting Step #3 - "link revision on pull request"
```

What I don't undestand is why the sep is even looking for a :latest tag. There is none. The above steps don't create one. The container registry does not contain one.
How to tell that build step to use the proper image tagged with `${_PR_NUMBER}-${SHORT_SHA}`?
Where can I dive into the magic here? Where is the definition of this magic build step?!

Thank you very much for any ideas.

Comment: What's the version of your deployment-previous that you have in  your container registry? Do you have a latest tagged version? Other version number? Sha number? Can you try to specify a version in your build step?

Comment: in the push image build step I upload the image as specified, tagged with PR number and short SHA: `${_PR_NUMBER}-${SHORT_SHA}`.
The template for this cloud run config comes from google: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/configure-deployment-previews#add-a-new-cloud-build-configuration

Comment: It's going to be hard to figure this one out without seeing the full execution logs cause at some point it should be getting the latest tag from somewhere but it's hard to know on which step it's getting it without the logs, Could you share that?

Answer (score 0):

When you don't specify an image tag, tools will always try to pull the `:latest` image.  In Cloud Build, you can specify a specific version of a builder image by simply including the **tag** in the **name** for your build step:

```
  - id: "link revision on pull request"
    name: "$_GCR_HOSTNAME/${PROJECT_ID}/deployment-previews:${_PR_NUMBER}-${SHORT_SHA}" # our custom builder
    args:
      [
        "set",
        "--project-id",
        "${PROJECT_ID}",
        "--region",
        "${_REGION}",
        "--service",
        "${_SERVICE_NAME}",
        "--pull-request",
        "${_PR_NUMBER}",
        "--repo-name",
        "${_GITHUB_REPO}",
        "--commit-sha",
        "${SHORT_SHA}",
      ]
```